# Reemplazar valores en un CSV Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

Estoy perdido con algo.
Tengo un archivo csv que lo importo con Pandas para poder convertirlo en un array de Numpy, y tengo la siguiente función para reemplazar valores en el archivo CSV original:

```
    # Cargamos el archivo en la variable data, como strings
    data_p = pd.read_csv(filename)
    data = np.array(data_p.values)
    # funcion saveData
    # Retorna el arreglo con el nuevo valor en los indices recibidos.
    # Guarda la información en el archivo
    def saveData(indicex,indicey,nuevo_valor):
        data[indicex][indicey] = nuevo_valor
        data_p.to_csv(filename,sep=',',mode='a')
        # np.savetxt(filename,data, delimiter=",",fmt="%s",header="Team,Group,Squad Number,Position,Player,Age,Club,Goals")
        return data
```

Pero cuando quiero usar la función no sobreescribe los datos, sino que duplica todos los datos del CSV desde la ultima fila hacia abajo, y esto lo hace segpun el número de veces que se repita el for.

```
for g in range(2):
    if goles_partido[g] != 0:
        info_equipo = data23.obtenerInfoEquipo(partido[g + 1].title())
        for i in range(goles_partido[g]):
            indice_gol = random.randint(0, info_equipo.shape[0])
            nombre_jugador_gol = info_equipo[indice_gol - 1, 4]
            print(nombre_jugador_gol)
            posicion_jugador_data = np.where(data23.data == nombre_jugador_gol)
            print(posicion_jugador_data)
            gol_temp = int(data23.data[posicion_jugador_data[0], -1])
            print(gol_temp)
            gol_temp += 1
            gol_temp = str(gol_temp)
            print(gol_temp)
            data23.data = data23.saveData(posicion_jugador_data[0], -1, gol_temp)
            print(data23.data[posicion_jugador_data[0], -1])
goles_partido = []
```

Los print son solamente para comprobar si los datos se sobreescriben correctamente en algun momento, cosa que no sucede.

Alguien podría ayudarme por qué sucede esto? Y que debo hacer para que se sobreescriba correctamente?

Gracias!

Comment: `mode='a'`, con esto haces que Pandas no sobrescriba el contenido del archivo, lo agrega a partir del contenido anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema era que se duplicaban los datos, lo revise y no se si es la solucion mas optima pero esto me fue bien para mi

```
data_p = pd.read_csv(filename)
data = np.array(data_p.values)
print(data)
    # funcion saveData
    # Retorna el arreglo con el nuevo valor en los indices recibidos.
    # Guarda la información en el archivo
def saveData(indicex,indicey,nuevo_valor):
    data[indicex][indicey] = nuevo_valor
    np.savetxt(filename,data, delimiter=",",fmt="%s",header="Team,Group,Squad Number,Position,Player,Age,Club,Goals")
    return data
saveData(1,1, "Hola")
```

espero haberte ayudado saludos